# How to use setfacl for only files in a directory leaving sub-directories' acl unchanged?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, access-control-list, ubuntu-18.04

I've been looking for ages but unable to find specific response to my need.
I want all the files in one of my directories to have acl set to rw for owner and group but the sub-directories in it should remain as is. Is it possible? If yes, how?
I've used `setfacl` with -R option but it changes the sub-directories as well.

My OS is ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `find . -type f -depth 1` with the `-exec` option to limit the depth.

Comment: Using `find` works but since I have millions of small files in the directory, it takes sooo long to process the command. I hoped it could be done using only `setfacl`.